# Annyang causes chrome ask to allow microphone before it starts

Tags: webkitspeechrecognition, annyang

I've added [Annyang]: https://github.com/TalAter/annyang to my AngularJS app, just as shown in the demo.
Problem is, that Chrome fires the pop up to allow using the microphone when the  application is up, and not only when start using Annyang.
Why is does it happen?

index.html:

script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/annyang/2.6.1/annyang.min.js">

Angular code:

```
    private onVoiceSearchStart() {
        if (annyang) {
              // Let's define a command.

              var commands = {
                'search for *searchString': function(searchString) { 
                    // run search
                }
              };

              // Add our commands to annyang
              annyang.addCommands(commands);

              // Start listening.
              annyang.start();
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The permission request dialog will pop up as soon as the browser's speech recognition engine is triggered to start listening. This happens when you call `annyang.start()`.

Comment: Thanks! that was it.

Comment: I'm glad it helped @Rajesh . Please mark my answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to it https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers